# Viewing Database off of iPhone with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm trying to see the contents of my sqlite database on an iPhone. I've read other posts that point me to Window->Organizer, but when I try to download from that menu I can only download the .xcappdata file. I have a paid developer account and I can see the files that are associated with the app, but I can't choose one to download. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the Download button in the Organizer. It will save the whole app sandbox to a folder with the `xcappdata` extension. Use Finder and navigate the folder to find the file(s) you need.

Comment: To be clear, after doing this, right-clicking on the file and selecting "Show Package Contents" will allow you to see inside the xcappdata, which should contain the sqlite file in AppData/Documents/(YourAppName), or alternatively you could cd into it from terminal